# Pass several arguments to function from map()

Tags: python

For example, if I want to detect all odd numbers in an array and set them to zero, I can use:

```
def setToZeroIfOdd(n):
   if n % 2 == 0:
      pass
   else:
      return 0

numbers = range(1,1000)

numbers = map(setToZeroIfOdd, numbers)
```

which works like a charm.

But when I try something like

```
def setToZeroIfDivisibleBy(n, divisor):
  if n % divisor == 0:
     return 0
  else:
     pass

numbers = map(setToZeroIfDivisibleBy(divisor=3), numbers)
```

it expects two arguments. Likewise,

```
numbers = map(setToZeroIfDivisibleBy, numbers, divisor=3)
```

does not work. How can I pass that `divisor` argument from within `map()`?

Comment: "which works like a charm." Certainly not. `pass` implicitly returns `None` here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9458271/1639625 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/38800245/1639625

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using lambda function

```
numbers = map(lambda n: setToZeroIfDivisibleBy(n, divisor=3), numbers)
```

And rather than `pass` did you mean `return n`?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make partial functions

```
from functools import partial

def setToZeroIfDivisibleBy(n, divisor):
  if n % divisor == 0:
     return 0
  else:
     pass

numbers = range(1,1000)

numbers = map(partial(setToZeroIfDivisibleBy, divisor=3), numbers)
```

Answer (score 8):

You make a function which returns a function:

```
def setToZeroIfDivisibleBy(divisor):
    def callback(n):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            pass

    return callback

numbers = map(setToZeroIfDivisibleBy(3), numbers)
```

BTW, you can entirely omit empty branches like `else: pass`; it doesn't do anything. Since it results in a `None`, I don't think that's what you want either. You probably want `return n` there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, instead of using `partial`, is to supply an infinite (or at least, long enough) sequence of 2nd arguments for the two-argument function:

```
from itertools import repeat
numbers = map(setToZeroIfDivisibleBy, numbers, repeat(3))
```

---

In Python 2, `map` will append `None` as necessary to the shorter of the two sequences to make them the same length. Assuming that will cause problems (either because your function cannot handle `None` as an input value or you end up with an infinite loop), you can either use `itertools.imap`, which stops after exhausting the shorter sequence:

```
from itertools import imap, repeat
numbers = list(imap(setToZeroIfDivisibleBy, numbers, repeat(3)))
```

or pass the length of `numbers` as a second argument to `repeat` so that the two sequences are the same length.

```
from itertools import repeat
numbers = map(setToZeroIfDivisibleBy, numbers, repeat(3, len(numbers)))
```